# Concurrency Thread Group in Distribution Mode

Tags: jmeter

Stress Scenario: Increase the number of users logged in until we notice lag and or the system crashed (Max 1500). Record number of total users logged in before problems are realized.
Expected Outcome: Determine through stress testing the upper limit of users that can be logged into application at any one time.

I have designed the below for the above scenario using Concurrency Thread group

1. In distribution Mode   with 1 Master Machine & 5 Salve Machines per machine with 300 Unique  Logins i.e total 1500 Login Credentials
2. Constant Throughput 50 Requests / Min
3. Iteration: 1

Question : When I executed the test in distribution mode 75 Users per 1 Min's Ramping, but as per the design it should take 40 min's right. Not able to get it how it is working.

Client want to see where it's breaking that's why I have given Only 1 Iteration & When app is not able to handle the request  Stop the Test.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"As per design" each slave machine will have 300 users up and running after 40 minutes so what you described in your "question" is "as per design"

Explanation: after complex calculations including usage of powerful statistical analysis tools and [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) I discovered that:

- 300 users in 40 minutes us 30 users in 4 minutes
- 30 users in 4 minutes is 15 users in 2 minutes

So JMeter will start with 15 users and each 2 minutes will be adding 15 more for next 40 minutes.

Given you have 5 slaves:

- for first 2 minutes of the test you will have 15 * 5 == 75 users
- for second 2 minutes of the test you will have 30 * 5 == 150 users
- etc.

More information:

- [JMeter Ramp-Up Period: The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period)
- [Apache JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)